# Magento 2.4.1 Layered navigation with custom product collection

Tags: product, collection, layered-navigation, magento2.4.1

I want to override category product collection on the category product page in front-end. I want to show collection according to attribute set. After customize collection layered navigation product count is not updating.

I am using plugin for modified default category product collection. I am using **getProductCollection()**. After plugin category product collection filtered by attribute set id but layered navigation is still showing same count. The custom condition is not applied on the layered navigation

Here is my code:

**app/code/Sunarc/ProductListpage/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
    <plugin name="seedolabs-catalog-layer-model" type="Sunarc\ProductListPage\Plugin\Model\Layer"/>
</type>
```

**app/code/Sunarc/ProductListpage/Plugin/Model/Layer.php**

```
 public function afterGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, $result){ $result->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',['eq'=>9]);
return $result;}
```

kindly help me

Screenshot for issue

[image: Layered navigation issue]

Comment: Please use beforeGetProductCollection and add filter over collection

Comment: I tried but not working can you please send me code so I can check

Comment: you are using elasticsearch ?

Comment: Yes, I am using elasticsearch 7

Comment: Any suggestion on this issue –

Comment: @Aish did you get solution ? I am facing same problem

Comment: No, I didn't got any solution on this. I am still checking this issue.

Comment: @Aish any luck with the fix? It has been a few months, and did you manage to accomplish this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Aish did you get solution ? I am facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code not work might because the product collection loaded somewhere, during Toolbar repair collection, you should create a custom filter append to the Layered Navigation.

You might check the Layer resolver:

- vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php:147
- $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);

**UPDATE**:

- Based on your detail, you are using elasticsearch, thus, you have to customize the request from Magento post to the ElasticSearch and filter it from ElasticSearch instead of filter the product collection from Magento.

Comment: Product is showing according to the filter but layered navigation is not working according to custom filter after add filter in to the prepareProductCollection function

Comment: Any suggestion on this issue –

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Have you got any answer?

Comment: I am facing same issue in layered navigation

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with plugin as @Arun pointed in the comment.

This is core `getProductionCollection` function:

```
public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

As you can read, the collection is stored inside `_productCollections` property, so it could be used after creation for other purposes like counting products inside toolbar.

I suggest you to use around plugin on `prepareProductCollection` method, so you can change your collection there:

```
<?php

namespace Sunarc\ProductListPage\Plugin\Model;

class Layer
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param Collection $collection
     */
    public function aroundPrepareProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, callable $proceed, $collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter("name", ["like" => "D%"]);
        return $proceed($collection);
    }
}
```

This plugin will add attribute filter by name starting with letter `D` to your collection.

Comment: I tried but not working. Product collection has been override but layered navigation product counts still not updating.

Comment: I've tested that on core 2.4.2 and it's working. Do you have any third party modules that changes that behaviour?

Comment: no I don't have any third party module. Can you please share code segment so I can check

Comment: Above screenshot showing issue . After apply your solution layered navigation issue has been not resolved . We are using elasticsearch 7

Comment: Any suggestion on this issue

Comment: @Aish Could you let me know if you find the solution for this issue.